# Карта кода и структура кода в Goland

Tags: golang, ide

Как в IDE Goland включить карту кода, как SublimeText примерно, справа прозрачная карта кода по которой можно как то ориентироваться по коду.
И второй вопрос как структурировать код, вот на пикче показывает просто все мои функции, но некоторые функции вкладываются в другие функции и не очень понятно, можно ли их как то в ручную образовать в группы?

[image: структура кода]

Comment: Спасибо за скрипн к вопросу. Лайк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Goland это называется структура проекта. Получить её легко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам нужно найти вкладочку `Structure` и щёлкнуть на неё. После этого, выбрать соответсвующий `package` и всё появится. Кажется, что я ответил сразу на два Ваших вопроса, покуда на скрине видно, что имеется древовидная структура методов.